# Can't install JPCAP library

Tags: java

I can't install JPCAP on my ubuntu machine.

It tells that depends on sun-java6-jdk & libpcap0.8. However I do have them installed in my system as you can see.

```
kujim@kujim:~/Downloads$ ldconfig -p | grep libpcap
    libpcap.so.0.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so.0.8
    libpcap.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcap.so
```

This is the error:

```
kujim@kujim:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get -f install jpcap
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
jpcap:i386 is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 jpcap:i386 : Depends: sun-java6-jdk:i386 but it is not installable
              Depends: libpcap0.8:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have tried the following command but no success.

```
kujim@kujim:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i --ignore-depends=sun-java6-jdk jpcap-0.7.deb
(Reading database ... 227615 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack jpcap-0.7.deb ...
Unpacking jpcap (0.7) over (0.7) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of jpcap:
 jpcap depends on sun-java6-jdk.
 jpcap depends on libpcap0.8.

dpkg: error processing package jpcap (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jpcap
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I also have jdk installed, forgot to upload the code. kujim@kujim:~/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_31$ ls /usr/lib/jvm/
default-java  java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64  java-7-openjdk-amd64

Answer (score 1):

apt-get is telling you that you're missing `sun-java6-jdk:i386` and `libpcap0.8:i386`, which are the 32-bit versions of these packages.  You have the 64-bit versions installed.

Try running `apt-get install sun-java6-jdk:i386 libpcap0.8:i386`.  The output should tell you something more about why those packages aren't installable.

Comment: hey, u just solved my problem. I had to install those libraries and now works like charm. Thx!

Comment: @KuJiM if you found the answer helpful please [consider accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)